# Magento programatically can't able to add multiple product

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

In Multiple product i can't able to add in cart

**controller.php**

```
public function addtocartAction(){
      /* Get Product id From Form Post */
        $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('productids');
      /* Get Product id From Form Post */

      /* Add Product in to Cart */
        $product=new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
        $product->load($product_id); // Product Id
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quote->addProduct($product); // quantity is 1
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init(); // tried commenting this too!
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        $this->_redirectReferer();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your product has been Added successfully...'); 
      /* Add Product in to Cart */
    }
```

`productids` contain 1,2,3 but i can add only one product what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know but you can try following code and also dont use `new`  its a bad practice

```
public function addtocartAction(){
  /* Get Product id From Form Post */
    $product_ids =  explode(",",$this->getRequest()->getPost('productids')) ;
  /* Get Product id From Form Post */
    foreach($product_ids as $product_id){
        /* Add Product in to Cart */
        $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->load($product_id); // Product Id
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quote->addProduct($product); // quantity is 1
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init(); // tried commenting this too!
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        $this->_redirectReferer();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your product has been Added successfully...'); 
      /* Add Product in to Cart */
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't understand this dont use new

Comment: forgot that I made other changes look at that and let me know

Comment: if you want to call `new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();` then magento has its own syntax for calling model, block and helper calss and in your case you can use  `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` it has same effect as yours code but it is with magento syntax

Comment: You are always welcome  :)

Answer (score 0):

`productids` is array so you  do this

```
 $product->load($product_id[0]);
```

to enter first product

Answer (score 0):

Add additional product to cart using observer events

Add below to your extension's config.xml

```
      <checkout_cart_save_after>
    <observers>
        <checkout_cart_save_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>customprice/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>additionalAddtocart</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
        </checkout_cart_save_after_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_cart_save_after>
```

In Observer.php

```
public function additionalAddtocart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{   
    $form_data=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    if(isset($form_data['additionalproducts']) && $form_data['additionalproducts'] !=''){ 
        $products=explode(',',$form_data['additionalproducts']); // passing additional products ids with comma seprate from product page in hidden field.
        foreach($products as $product_id){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $qty=1;// change as per your task
            $totalprice;// using your price calculation logic here and pass price
            $quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
            $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($totalprice);// Use it when want update price
            $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($totalprice); // Use it when want update price
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }
    }

}
```